# Serializing an object containing another object (nested objects) using the KvwSerializable interface in KSOAP2

Tags: android, serialization, ksoap2

I'm trying to get my app to communicate with a WCF. I have already serialized a class Query using the KvmSerializable interface in the KSOAP2 library.

How can I serialize a class LogInQuery that contains (but not extends) the Query class as a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to do, was to implement the KvmSerializable interface, nothing special.